# Hibernate Search 5.5.3 - Sort by collection size no longer working

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I've been trying to migrate from Hibernate Search 5.5.2 to 5.5.3, and I've run into an issue with one of my sort fields. This is the code that was working with 5.5.2 (or maybe it wasn't working, and just wasn't throwing errors?)

```
public class CollectionCountBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field(name, FieldType.INTEGER).sortable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object object, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if (object == null || (!(object instanceof Collection))) {
            return;
        }
        Collection<?> coll = (Collection<?>) object;
        int size = coll.size();

        IntField field = new IntField(name, size, (luceneOptions.getStore() != Store.NO) ? Field.Store.YES : Field.Store.NO);
        document.add(field);
    }

}

...

@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, norms = Norms.YES, index = Index.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = CollectionCountBridge.class)
@IndexedEmbedded
@OneToMany
public Set<MyCollection> getMyCollection() {
    return myCollection;
}
```

The code essentially stores the size of the collection as a sortable field. This was based on the documentation which suggested if I need to define a sortable field via a bridge, then I have to implement MetadataProvidingFieldBridge to mark it sortable. The documentation however shows only an example for a string field, whereas I need to use a numeric field. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#sortablefield-annotation

So following the upgrade to 5.5.3 I started getting errors like:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000307: Sort type INT is not compatible with string type of field 'myCollection'
```

I've tried adding the field to the document in a variety of ways, and nothing seems to work. Some things I've tried:

```
luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, size, document);

document.add(new SortedNumericDocValuesField(name, size));
//this throws an error on index
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot change DocValues type from SORTED_NUMERIC to NUMERIC for field "myCollection"

public class CollectionCountBridge extends NumberBridge
```

So, my question is, what is the correct way to add a sortable numeric field to the index, via a bridge, as of 5.5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's not a bug.

You have to add a corresponding NumericDocValuesField to your document to enable sorting. We will improve that in the future but for now, that's what you have to do.

Additionally, I wouldn't recommend you to add the field with the same name as the default one, you'd better index the collection size with another field name.

Your FieldBridge should look like this:

```
public class CollectionCountBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {
    private static final String COUNT_SUFFIX = "_count";

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field(name + COUNT_SUFFIX, FieldType.INTEGER).sortable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object object, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if (object == null || (!(object instanceof Collection))) {
            return;
        }
        Collection<?> coll = (Collection<?>) object;
        int size = coll.size();

        luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name + COUNT_SUFFIX, size, document);
        document.add(new NumericDocValuesField(name + COUNT_SUFFIX, size.longValue()));
    }
}
```

And when sorting, use a new SortField( "myCollection_count", SortField.Type.LONG ) ).

Comment: Thank you very much, it all seems to be working well now!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've hit a bug here. For a custom bridge as yours we are failing to properly detect the numeric encoding type. I've filed [HSEARCH-2292](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2292) for this.

As a work-around, you may create a transient property in your entity which exposes the collection size. To this property, you add `@Field` and `@SortableField` which should add the required fields to the index, using the correct types.